# Implement iAd interstitial view in magazine App using Baker

Tags: objective-c, iad

Differently from other frameworks, baker framework creates multiple views for each HTML page provided. I habe succesfully implemented iAd network as a banner, but I was wondering if anyone tried out the full page interstitial advertisements between view transition. It would be nice to share the code to instantiate iAd between pages

Comment: Please read the Stackoverflow FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple iAd programming guide has a full sample project that has boiler plate code for doing what you need. See the iAdInterstitialSuite example here -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iAdInterstitialSuite/Introduction/Intro.html